# I am deploying a restFull webservice webapp on weblogic 12.2.1.2 and It is failing

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

Hi I am having one restfull webservice which is getting deployed prior to version `weblogic 12.2.1.2` but on `weblogic 12.2.1.2` it is not getting deployed. and throws the below error:

```
<Oct 11, 2017, 8:16:22,462 PM IST> <Warning> <Munger> <BEA-2156203> <A version attribute was not found in element "web-app" in the deployment descriptor /u01/xxx/xxxx/webapps/xx/WEB-INF/web.xml. A version attribute is required, but this version of the WebLogic Server will assume that the latest version is used. Future versions of WebLogic Server will reject descriptors that do not specify the Java EE version. To eliminate this warning, add an appropriate "version=" to element "web-app" in the deployment descriptor.>
<Oct 11, 2017, 8:16:22,620 PM IST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.xxx.xx.xx.xxx.JerseyConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Oct 11, 2017, 8:16:22,621 PM IST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Oct 11, 2017, 8:16:22,624 PM IST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Oct 11, 2017, 8:16:22,624 PM IST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Oct 11, 2017, 8:21:37,36 PM IST> <Error> <org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider> <BEA-000000> <[failed to localize] none.or.multiple.beans.available(class com.xxx.xx.xx.JerseyConfig)>
```

I have tried with the `version` attribute in `web.xml` but didn't work. and thrown the same error.

Env. Details:

```
Java-1.7 & 1.8
weblogic-12.2.1.2
Servlet-api-2.4
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <display-name>xxx</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            WEB-INF/classes/configs/*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.javaetmoi.core.spring.JBoss5XmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>--> 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.xx.xx.xx.JerseyConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>localFilesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>configs</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/xxx</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/xxx</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Seems you are missing web.xml version attribute, for example... ```<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">```

Comment: I have tried with version attribute also but after that other errors are coming. Doesn't work

Comment: Also you need to set up ```@ApplicationPath(/"your_path")``` in a class, or configure the Jersey Servlet in the web.xml file.

Comment: @Rafel Guillen Updated my questionwith the web.xml,  I have configured @ApplicationPath("/") in JerseyConfig

Answer (score 0):

This is an example web.xml from Jersey Examples, note there is an initialization parameter that points to the Jersey Application Class

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.bookstore.webapp.MyApplication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.bookstore.webapp.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- pass to next filter if Jersey/App returns 404 -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.bookstore.webapp.MyApplication</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        // Resources.
        packages(Bookstore.class.getPackage().getName());

        // MVC.
        register(JspMvcFeature.class);

        // Logging.
        register(LoggingFilter.class);

        // Tracing support.
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, TracingConfig.ON_DEMAND.name());
    }
}
```